# Extract QDM elements from EHR to calculate eCQM

Tags: hl7-fhir, cda, openehr

How to get quality data model(QDM) elements from EHR's raw data to calculate eCQM? I know EHR can export data using standards like CDA and FHIR by HL7. But how to extract QDM elements from these standards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For quality reporting, there are lots of different ways to do this. Many EHRs already support extracting QDM data in the form of Quality Reporting Document Architecture (QRDA) documents to support CMS quality reporting requirements. For FHIR specifically, there is a set of FHIR profiles called QI-Core (Quality Improvement), that builds on the US-Core profiles and provides a skeletal mapping from QDM to the QI-Core profiles:

http://hl7.org/fhir/us/qicore/qdm-to-qicore.html

Comment: For QDM elements there is one to one mapping with CCDA templates to generate QRDA. But I’m unable to map the template ids given in the implementation guid of QRDA with the samples provided.

>>QRDA IG
hl7.org/implement/standards/product_brief.cfm?product_id=35 

>>CCDA samples
github.com/chb/sample_ccdas

Can you please help me with this?